# C++: ODR violation for member functions defined outside of class body but enclosed within header guard (as shown in YouCompleteMe plugin)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, youcompleteme

I have a simple header file as shown below.

```
  #ifndef PERSON_H
  #define PERSON_H

  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

  struct Person {
      string name;
      string address;
      auto get_name() const -> string;
  };

 string Person::get_name() const {  // Function 'get_name' defined in a header file; function definitions in header files can lead to ODR violations
          return this -> name;
  }

  #endif
```

Question:
Even though the Person::get_name() function is defined outside of the struct Person, this function is defined inside the header guard PERSON_H. YouCompleteMe tool (presume using g++), it states it violates ODR. Why would it violates ODR? This function will never be defined more than once since it's control by header guard PERSON_H. I am not sure if there is a bug in the YouCompleteMe tool because i noticed i don't get the same warning message using visual studio.

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Include guards prevent a single file from being included multiple times in a single translation unit. For instance, if the file `A.hpp` includes `B.hpp` and `C.hpp`, and `B.hpp` _also_ includes `C.hpp`, an include guard on `C.hpp` will prevent multiple copies of `C` from appearing in `A.hpp`. This will _not_ do anything to stop `C.hpp` from appearing multiple times in multiple different translation units, which constitutes an ODR violation if C contains a non-inline definition.

Comment: Thanks. I wish i could everyone the correct answer. Just curious. Is there a way i can make multiple checks to indicate correct answers? I like your answers too but i have to give it to Ben since he has the same answer as yours and he responded first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be included in multiple compilation units. If you mark the definition `inline` it should be happy.

Comment: You are saying e.g. if i include this header file in a.cc & b.cc .. hence this Person:get_name() will be appended to a.cc as well as b.cc compliation unit?

Comment: That’s right. If you only have one compilation unit, the header you have should be ok. But don’t: it should either be inlined or in its own source file.

Comment: @yapkm01 when the compiler (preprocessor, really) finds an include statement it effectively replaces the `#include` with a copy of the named file.

Comment: @user4581301 Thx.